# How to 'link' two music directories when dual booting Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, music, directory

I'm dual booting Win7 and 12.04 and I want to link my two music folders together.

Basically I want the contents of my Win7 music directory to appear in my Ubuntu music directory.

Comment: Do you require that the Windows music be browseable in `~/Music`?  Because you should be able to add the second music folder to your Rhythmbox or Banshee music library if you just want it to appear in those programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Can you see the Windows drive from Ubuntu?
   If yes, then you can see whatever changes you make in Windows, directly in Ubuntu.
   You have to find the Windows music folder in nautilus and then `Right click` → `Properties` → `Location`. This is the "source" location, e.g. `/media/Windows/Users/Nick/Music`
2. Do you have anything in the Ubuntu music folder?
   If yes, you need to move the contents to another folder, e.g. on `Desktop`
3. Now you need to find the path for the Ubuntu music folder. Do what we did on step 1. This is the "target" location, e.g. `/home/nick/Music`
4. The Ubuntu music folder should be empty by now, delete it
5. Open a terminal and write:`ln -s "source" "target"` substituting with the paths we found in steps 1 and 3, e.g. `ln -s /media/Windows/Users/Nick/Music /home/nick/Music`
6. If you had data in your Ubuntu music folder in step 2, you can now move them back to the new folder.

Comment: If you have followed step-5, that is, creating Symbolic link that points to Windows partition, it may not have mounted when you start your computer and you may need to mount it either manually or you can auto-mount it upon startup using file `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @Kush That's true, but I assume that he will use nautilus to access the music folder which will auto-mount the folder

Comment: I had to use " ln -s /backup/somedir/Music /home/user/  " after deleting the Music directory otherwise I got " failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/user/Music’: No such file or directory "

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal, use `ln -s source destination`, because your folders reside in different mount points you must use `-s` option in the `ln` command

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the changes I make in my destination directory occur in my source directory?

Comment: just link two folders use that command, then they will be sync completely

Comment: I have tested your command, but what I get in the destination directory is a symbolic link to the source directory. So what I'm having to do is go into the destination directory and click a link to the source directory. 

What I'm wanting is for the contents of the source directory to be displayed in destination directory, so that when I go into the  destination directory, I immediately see the contents of the source directory. I've tried running:

ln -s source/* destination

but this just gave me symbolic links to the contents of the source directory